# Calculate current/voltage: Diode in parallel with resistor

Tags: voltage, current, diodes

Without using `Kirchoff`, I want to understand how to calculate a circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEa9tA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Perhaps the values I used will not provide the `0.7V` needed for the diode. But this is the general diagram.
I tried this:

```
I1=I2+I3
I2=(5-I1*47)/22
I3=(5-0.7-I1*47)/2
```

Is there another way except for using `Kirchoff`?

Comment: That diode is in series with a resistor, not in parallel.

Comment: @Transistor Maybe he means in parallel with R2?

Comment: Of course. Better focus on the real problem

Comment: Calculate \$I_1\$ based on your equations (i.e. assuming the diode is conducting). If there's a conflict in the resultant loop voltages and currents, then the diode cannot be conducting.

Comment: What's the problem with your equations? They seem fine, so long as the diode is actually conducting, and I'm pretty sure it is -- if you took out the right branch, the voltage would be ~1.6 V due to the divider of 22 Ω and 47 Ω alone, so there's enough voltage for the diode to conduct. The actual voltage will be less once you figure the right brach into account, I'd guess closer to 1 V. Either way, seems like a perfectly valid way of going about the problem.

Comment: Just solve the KCL: \$\frac{V_x}{R_1}+\frac{V_x}{R_2}+\frac{V_x-700\:\text{mV}}{R_3}=\frac{V_\text{CC}}{R_1}\$. This works out quickly to \$V_x\approx 805\:\text{mV}\$ with your values. If you want to be more mathy about it, you could solve two simultaneous equations and have to supply the saturation current for the diode as well as its emission coefficient. But then the equation gets a little more complicated. But then the answer is closer to  \$V_x\approx 862\:\text{mV}\$ using 1.752 as the emission coefficient and 2.52 nA as the saturation current (from LTspice model.)